# What's a good word for a category of non-technical blog posts?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms

I have a website mostly devoted to technical blog posts. In the main navigation there are links for JavaScript and CSS, which take you to a list of posts about those topics.

My question is, what should I call the link for my non-technical blog posts? I was thinking of just using the word "Blog," but really, the whole thing is a blog, so it doesn't do a good job of describing what this section is. I was also thinking about calling it "Personal," but I don't like that either, because they aren't all personal posts, they are about a bunch of different things, the only thing they have in common is being non-technical.

I don't have much experience with the tags on this site, so please edit them if you want.

Thanks.

Here are some words I have been considering:

*Bulletin, Prose, English, Writing, Verse, Essays*

Comment: Why don't you call it "non-technical" ?

Comment: @ermanen It is a little to long, and it is defined in the negative, which I'm not excited about. It seems like there would be something better.

Comment: If your website's technical posts target one or more smaller audiences of specialists, you could distinguish the list of nontechnical posts by labeling it "General Interest." This would have the additional benefit of implying that even readers interested in one or more of the special-interest categories might like the nontechnical ones as well—since "general interest" doesn't mean "only for nonspecialists."

Answer (score 2):

Tech is Zeros&Ones, so you could call it **Twos&Threes**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**miscellaneous**" or "**miscellany**".

> [miscellaneous:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miscellaneous) composed of or containing a variety of things; mixed; varied
>
> [miscellany](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miscellany): a collection of various items or parts.

Or simply "**other**".

---

"**miscellaneous posts**" is a very common usage also.

Comment: This is a decent suggestion, but its too broad -- it doesn't exclude photo galleries, online games, cat videos or comment threads. Something like "prose" works... but I don't want to exclude poetry. Maybe my question was too broad.

Comment: Yes its broad but miscellaneous covers that. Though it is more like nontechnical miscellaneous items. As I suggested the simplest solution would be using "other". Maybe just "writings". Or you can use "casual" (perhaps with a noun after)

Comment: While the word literally means that just about anything could be included, in the context of a set of categories the implication is that it means things that don't belong to one of the specific categories.

Answer (score 1):

Joey Hess calls it "lay" on [his blog](http://joeyh.name/blog/lay/), so you could use that or maybe "lay person" to be clearer. I suppose you could also call them "accessible," but in the context it would probably sound like you're writing about accessibility online or paying yourself a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

How about calling them [rambles](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ramble)?

It has lots of nice connotations, including talking aimlessly, if you're not taking yourself too seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Call it "the insane ramblings of a mad arab".

Comment: This is suitable for the Necronomicon, but probably not this guy's blog. Anyone who doesn't know this reference may find it offensive, so you should probably flesh out your answer a bit to explain it.

Comment: @KitFox I was about to flag it when I read your comment.

Comment: When the journal's main topic is a technical subject, as it is the case for Watson's blog, the journal owner usually call their off-topic journal records "rants", "ramblings", "personal item", "personal note", "miscellanea" in general, or by the general subject touched upon in such a record. I just found it strange that someone would ask for a particular name categorizing such things:) so I proposed a well-known quip from the Necronomicon.

Answer (score 1):

The word "**asides**" can indicate that these posts are set apart from the main topic of the blog.

"**Tangents**" may work if the posts are at least loosely related to the main topic.

"**Curiosities**" might work if your non-technical blog posts are interesting enough to catch the reader's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these work, or capable of deviation into something that works?

- Posts
- Non-Technical Posts
- Blog Posts
- Open Posts
- Miscellaneous Posts
- Rambles
- Rants
- Free Posts
- Basic Posts
- General Interest Posts
- Bulletins
- Ideas
- Thought Bubbles
- Concepts
- Opinionaries
- Brain Storms
- "Other Stuff"
- Chains of Thought
- *Name everything technical "meta".*
- Casual Posts
- Analog? Opposite of digital/technical?
- *Name everything technical "Technical".*
- Other